# How to replace the last element of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I need to replace last element in array.

I know, that I can use `filter` method to replace element, but how to replace the latest element?
How do I know the index of element?
Should I check size of array and replace latest element?
or maybe remove latest element and add new?

Generally i'm adding elements using unshift:

```js
this.array.unshift({
    name: cmd.event.type,
    id: cmd.event.id,
    xpath: cmd.event.xpath,
    x: `x: ${xparam}`,
    y: `y: ${yparam}`,
})
```

and what should I do to replace latest `this.array` element?

Comment: `this.array[this.array.length - 1] = /* Whatever you want */`

Comment: @GuerricP in Vue 2 this is not reactive

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `splice` method :

```
this.array.splice(this.array.length - 1, 1, {
        name: cmd.event.type,
        id: cmd.event.id,
        xpath: cmd.event.xpath,
        x: `x: ${xparam}`,
        y: `y: ${yparam}`,
      })
```

the 1st param : the element index to be replaced

2nd param: the delete count

3rd param : your new element to insert

for Vue 2 you could use `this.$set` method :

```
 this.$set(this.array,this.array.length - 1,{
    name: cmd.event.type,
    id: cmd.event.id,
    xpath: cmd.event.xpath,
    x: `x: ${xparam}`,
    y: `y: ${yparam}`,
  })
```

Comment: Using `splice` will preserve reactivity, no need to use `Vue.$set`. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays

Comment: `splice(-1)` will simply work

Answer (score 2):

You could get latest element index with `length` property

```
 const latestElement = this.array[this.array.length - 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

using index is IMHO more readable than splice when replacing the last item

```
this.array[this.array.length - 1] = {
    ...item props...
};
```

maybe pop&push is even nicer

```
this.array.pop()
this.array.push({
    ...item props...
});
enter code here
```

but you wrote that you are adding items using unshift, which adds to beginning of array, so if you ment "latest" as "latest added by unshift", then replacing is just

```
this.array[0] = {
    ...item props...
};
```

or just remove latest added

```
this.array.shift();
```

as it removes forst element in array